# Composing linear equation system for a matrix from multiple correspondences

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Consider the following equation system:

$\boldsymbol{x}_i = \boldsymbol{KPT_jTX_i}$

where $\boldsymbol{x}_i$ is a $(3 \times 1)$ vector, $\boldsymbol{K}$ is a $(3 \times 3)$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{P}$ is a $(3 \times 4)$ matrix, $\boldsymbol{T_j}$ and $\boldsymbol{T}$ are $(4 \times 4)$ matrices, $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ is a $(4 \times 1)$ vector. Furthermore, $i \in [1, 6]$ and $j \in [1, 3]$, such that $i=1, i=2$ correspond to $j=1$, $i=3, i=4$ correspond to $j=2$ etc. $\boldsymbol{T}$ only has 6 degrees of freedom and is of the form

$T = \left(\begin{matrix} \boldsymbol{R} & \boldsymbol{t} \\\boldsymbol{0} & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$

where $\boldsymbol{R}$ is a $(3 \times 3)$ rotation matrix ($3$ dof), $\boldsymbol{t} = (t_1, t_2, t_3)^T$, $\boldsymbol{0} = (0, 0, 0)$.

$\boldsymbol{x}_i, \boldsymbol{K}, \boldsymbol{P}, \boldsymbol{T}_j$ and $\boldsymbol{X}_i$ are given $\forall i, j$. How can one solve these six given equations for $\boldsymbol{T}$? I have solved similar equation systems before by vectorizing the matrix and stacking the given equations on top of each other to form the system matrix, but they had different structure from this one and I am really out of ideas here.

Comment: Are you only interested in a closed-form solution? Or would it be sufficient to use a minimum sum of squared errors approach and solve the system of equations numerically?

Comment: @AxelKemper Yes, I am generally interested in an analytical solution. However it might be interesting to see a least squares approach, maybe it could give some hints.